# What is the scope of global variables between two functions

Tags: python, variables

I am but confused over here. Should I declare a variable a global variable if it is already set in a function?
I mean

```
def function1():
   global var1, var2
   var1 = 2
   var2 = 3

def function2():
   global var1, var2    <-------Should i mention in every function where I use those variable?
   ans = var1 + var 2
```

If it is not required, then can I do like this ?

```
def function 1():
    var1 = 2
    var2 = 4

def funciton2():
   ans = var1+var2

def function3():
   global var1, var2
   (no codes here)
```

Is there a way to get list of all variables used in script and sort out which of them are global ?

Comment: "can I do like this" Did you try? Variables are global, not names. A name can be used both for a global and local variable; Python has no way to know you mean a global variable unless you tell it to, or clearly don't have a local variable of the same name.

Comment: If you don't modify the variable in a function, then it will be implicitly global.  If you do modify a variable in a function, then you need to decide whether you want it to be local or global.  For local, do nothing.  For global, declare it global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `globals()` to give you a dictionary of global variables.
You only need to use the keyword `global` if you plan to update a global variable, not if you are trying to access its value

You do need to assign them outside of the function so in your case

```
var1 = 1 # outside function, can be used as global variable
var2 = 2

def function1():
   global var1, var2
   var1 = 2 # as global is used, from here on var1 will have the value 2
   var2 = 3

def function2():
# as you are not assigning a value to var1,2 but only access their value so  
# you do not need to use the global keyword
   ans = var1 + var2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `global` in any function that will assign a value to that variable. `global` tells the function that the name isn't in its local namespace. When you just use the variable, python will try the local namespace, not find the variable, and then fall back to the global namespace. When you try to set a variable, python can't know whether you meant a local variable that happens to have the same name or a global one. Hence the `global` decoration.

In your first example, you need global in function1 because you assign the variables.

```
def function1():
   global var1, var2
   var1 = 2
   var2 = 3
```

You don't need it in function2 because you only use them, you don't assign anything to them.

```
def function2():
   ans = var1 + var2
```